# Is there a general command line tool to manage fan speed?

Tags: linux, centos, command-line, fan

I've to manage 50 workstations of different brands, mostly DELL T76** and HP Z800. They are all installed on CentOS 7.4.

I would like to have **a tool to test fan speed in command line**, not only CPU fans.

Is there such a general tool or will it always be depending on the motherboard?

Comment: I'm guessing you already looked under `/sys/class/thermal`?

Comment: No. I don't know this.

Comment: Google for `lm_sensors`, `sensors-detect` and `fancontrol`. The latter is a console tool to manipulate fan speeds, if your kernel can control the fan, that is. Neither new nor hidden ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solve this using **lm_sensors** as suggested by @bananguin. Here is an explanation for the basic usage:

*To install on CentOS:*
`sudo yum install lm_sensors`

*To set this up:*
`sudo sensors-detect`
This will detect and setup the various hardware. The "safe" answers are the defaults.

*Finally, using `sensors` command* will display the value for the previously detected hardware.
Also, I'm using [Watch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command to check live updates.

---

Fancontrol is based on pwm-capable sensors and it's apparently not my case.